# Post request to graphql server not responding

Tags: node.js, json, http, graphql

I am trying to make a POST request to my graphql server that I have running on localhost:4000. To get my users I was using

```
getUsers(){
    var query = `{users(id:""){username}}`
   fetch('http://localhost:4000/graphql', {
     method:'POST',
     headers: {
       'Content-Type' :'application/json',
       'Accept': 'application/json',
     },
     body: JSON.stringify({
       query,
     })
   })
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(res => console.log('data returned', res))
```

this wasn't working so I made a curl request to see what was wrong,

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:4000/graphql -H "Content-Type: application/json "-d "{"query": "{users(id:""){username}}"
```

After I ran this I kept getting,

```
Unexpected token q in JSON at position
```

After looking up this issue on google first I found a tutorial that I thought might be able to help. Following the tutorial I changed my code to

```
  getUsers(){
    var query = `{users(id:""){username}}`
   fetch('http://localhost:4000/graphql', {
     method:'POST',
     headers: {
       'Content-Type' :'application/json',
       'Accept': 'application/json',
     },
     body: JSON.stringify({
       query,
     })
   })
   //.then(r => r.json())
   .then(res => res.text())
   .then(text => console.log('data returned', text))
```

which still didn't log anything.
So i ran one last curl to attempt to solve this problem

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:4000/graph0ql -d "{"query": "{users(id:""){username}}"
```

which kept returning

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Must provide query string."}]}
```

Now I'm stuck and I don't know what to try next.
I checked the query string and it gives me the intended response in graphiql and the url is correct as well. My angular frontend server (from which I am making this request) is running on localhost:4200

Comment: Your curl requests are failing because you're not escaping the inside double quotes. That's unrelated to whatever issue you're having on the front end. The `fetch` code itself looks fine. However, your question doesn't actually explain what behavior you're seeing. All you say is "this wasn't working". Please update your question with more details -- at least show what's getting logged to the console

Comment: Under each curl I have included what was logged into the console

Comment: Like I said, the curl requests are wrong -- whatever error they return is not relevant to your front end issue.

Comment: What is shown in the console when you call `console.log` on the front end side? I see you're calling it here: `console.log('data returned', res)`... so what does that say?

Comment: As far as I remember it wasn’t showing anything

Comment: Just checked on it and the console is not showing anything. My node terminal however is showing undefined a lot but it doesn’t seem to add another undefined when I refresh

Answer (score 0):

Ok I feel pretty dumb. I didn’t call my function correctly. It works all that’s left is to actually use the data

Answer (score -1):

The issue is how you're passing the query object. Try to update it into something like:

```
getUsers(){
  var query = `query getUsers { users(id:"") { username } }`
  fetch('http://localhost:4000/graphql', {
    method:'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type' :'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: query,
    })
  })
  //.then(r => r.json())
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(text => console.log('data returned', text))
}
```

Comment: What OP is using is called query shorthand syntax. While including the `query` keyword and an operation name is good practice, using shorthand won't cause errors